# Add php to js file

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I am working on a USA map with states to show which states have available properties by changing the color of the state.
I am using Leaflet for the map and have used the Interactive Choropleth Map (https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) as a basis to build this.

I have added `"availability":"2"` to the `us-states.js` file, this is where the number of properties will be shown. I would like to insert a php query 
into the `.js` file to pull the number of properties for that state.  Here is a sample from the `us-states.js` file so that you can see the layout:

```
{"type":"Feature","id":"02","properties":{"name":"North Carolina","availability":"2"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-131.602021,55.117982],
```

And I am using this to change color:

```
    // get color depending on population density value
    function getColor(d) {
        return d > 1 ? '#e1cb7f' :

                          '#173e34';
    }

    function style(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 1.9,
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.availability)
        };
}
```

This is my php query:

```
<?php $count = array('post_type' => 'property', 'meta_key' => 'state', 'meta_value' => 'NC'); $myquery = new WP_Query($count);  ?>
```

and I have tried to add this to the js file, but it will not work:

```
"availability":"<?php echo json_encode($myquery->found_posts) ?>"
```

If I manually add the number of properties to the us-states.js file the color does change on the map, so the color change part is working, I just cannot get the php to work in the .js file.

Here is my webpage:  https://www.thekeithcorp.com/interactive-map/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where in the js file are you adding that?

Comment: Likely your web server will not parse js files for php code.  You can try renaming the file to us-states.php (and the references to it).

Comment: Rename us-states.js to us-states.php and add header('Content-Type: application/javascript'); to the first line. In addition to your PHP.

Comment: Perhaps there's a different way to achieve what you're wanting. Every time I've thought it would be nice to stick some php in a JS code snippet, it was a problem with my program's design. How would you feel about instead making an endpoint to get the data through an ajax request?

Comment: If I change us-states.js to us-states.php can the file now be called using:   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/us-states.php">"></script>
I also added <?php header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
to the file.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

1. Execute the query
2. Register the script using wp_register_script
3. Localize the registered script with the result of the query using wp_localize_script
4. Enqueue the script using wp_enqueue_script which references the JavaScript array that WordPress adds before the registered script

Answer (score 0):

on WordPress, can pass variables to JS, eg. with the theme's `functions.php`:

```
function localize() {

    $items = WP_Query ...

    wp_register_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), false, true );

     $script_vars = ["features" => []];
     for($i=0; $i < $items.size(); $i++) {

        array_push($script_vars['features'], (object) array(
             "id" => 2,
             "type" => "Feature",
             "properties" => (object) array(
                 "name" => "North Carolina",
                 "availability"=> 2
             ),
             "geometry" => (object) array(
                 "type" => "MultiPolygon",
                 "coordinates"=> [ ... ]
             )
        ));

    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );
    wp_localize_script('custom', 'script_vars', $script_vars);
}

if( !is_admin()) {
     add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "localize", 10);
}
```

while you just could change the file-name suffix from [.js](https://www.thekeithcorp.com/wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master/assets/js/us-states.js) to [.php](https://www.thekeithcorp.com/wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master/assets/js/us-states.php) ...however, when integrating the map with WordPress posts, it's better to localize or to use WP AJAX for loading the data asynchronously - or even cache the HTML output, which may not change that much, except when something is being added.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this!

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using this in the functions file:

```
wp_register_script( 'scount', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/us-states.js' );

// Localize the script with our data that we want to use
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'property',
  'fields' => 'ids',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'state',
      'value' => 'NC'
    )
  )
);
$results = new WP_Query($args);
$completed = count($results->posts);
wp_localize_script( 'scount', 'completed', $completed );

   // The script can be enqueued now or later.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scount' );
```

And using this in the json file:

```
( JSON.stringify(completed) )}
```

Note there is no ";" at the end!